# CLion IDE issue while using dlopen / libdl.co -ldl flags

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ide, dlopen, clion

I am testing a simple issue in CLion and am stumped:
it appears that I am not able to include functionality to use dlopen in a basic hello world case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   cout << "Hello, World!" << endl;

   char * file = (char*)"/path/to/file";
   dlopen(file, RTLD_NOW);


   return 0;
}
```

the above fails with undefined reference to `dlopen'
I am on 14.04 Ubuntu - 64 bit 
using boilerplate CMakeLists.txt file.
It appears I am not linking the libdl.so, even if I include -ldl flag
Could use some help

CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(testENC)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ldl  -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(testENC ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Comment: Can you show us your `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)  
project(testENC)
quoting the file:
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -ldl  -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(testENC ${SOURCE_FILES})

Comment: Have a look at [`target_link_libraries()`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/command/target_link_libraries.html).

Comment: I think `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` are *compilation* flags, you'll want to add a *linking* flag. But as I said, you should use CMake's built-in functionality for that, rather than messing with variables.

Answer (score 2):

received a working solution from CLion crew - it works!

I need to ad the following:

target_link_libraries(testENC ${CMAKE_DL_LIBS})